# What happens after a JUnit method has been executed?

Tags: java, junit, singleton

I have a JUnit class which deals with testing the clock in my system. The clock has a method `jump(long milliSeconds` which basically makes the clock jump to the specified time and thus sets the instance field of clock's `currentTime` to the parameter passed to the jump method.

So I have three JUnit methods. In the first I'm simply testing that the current time of the clock is 0, because I haven't invoked anything on the clock. Then I'm just testing that making the clock jump to a specified time once is reflected on the current time correctly. Lastly, I'm invoking the jump method a few time and after each jump I'm testing whether the current time is correct.

The problem I'm having is that sometimes my JUnit tests pass sometimes they fail. Assume I run the above three JUnit methods once, and it passes. That's fine. Then if I run the three again, then the first one fails because the current time of the clock is NOT 0 anymore but instead the current time is the last jump that was invoked in last test.

I'm confused about this because I thought that after executing all three JUnit methods sequentially it doesn't "remember" what it did if I run the tests again.

So does that require me to initialize the current time to be 0 in the `@Before setUp()` ? The thing is it's only sometimes that the above occurs. If I wait 5 minutes and run it again. It runs fine. Then if I immediately run it after again, I get the same error.

Has it perhaps something to do with the fact that I have declared the Clock class as final? Or that I have enforced the Singleton design pattern on it?

Comment: It would be helpful if you shared some code of your test class and the class that your are trying to test.

Comment: @Jatt, JUnit does not provides a clean way to do this, to run test unit in some specified order you should use TestNG. My point is that JUnit could run first testJumpingToSpecifiedTimeIsReflectedOnCurrentTime() and here you are setting the unique clock instance in 10000, so when JUnit runs testInitialTimeIsZero() it will fails. If this helps I'll publish it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You designed the Clock as a singleton: there is only one instance of Clock per classloader: `Clock.INSTANCE`. So obviously, if a method of a test affects the state of the clock, the next method will find this clock with this new state.

You've just rediscovered one of the reasons why singleton is an anti-pattern: it's hard to unit-test. Every test should not assume anything about the clock, and put it in a well-known initial state before testing.

Or you could simply design the Clock as a plain old Java object that you can instantiate in the setup of your test, and use an IOC container to inject a unique instance of Clock in your beans at runtime.

Also, note that unit tests are supposed to be independant from each other. You might want to execute all tests, or only one of them, and they should be able to run in any order.

Comment: Thanks. I understand what's happening now. But, do you in general discourage the use of the Singleton design pattern?

Comment: Yes, I do discourage the use of the singleton pattern most of the time. When you use a dependency injection framework, you quickly realize that singetons are unneeded.

Answer (score 0):

In JUnit the ordering of test-method invocations is not guaranteed, this is explained in the Junit [FAQ](http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/faq/faq.htm) section.

Your implementation is using a singleton, so as exposed before the order in which JUnit runs the test is going to affect the test results.

It's not a good practice that tests depends from each others, but if you need to ensure that you could use TestNG.

To fix that use a simple POJO class and let some DI framework handle that. If it's a constraint and you should preserve your class as it, test it with TestNG or rewrite your tests to ensure the order that you need. I.e: I think that a good test could be check that a lower specified time could throws an Exception.